# backtotop.js bug: box is always visible in Firefox 29

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    // JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

This should hide the box until you have scrolled to about 100px from the top. It does work in every browser until the latest Firefox update came out. Any suggestions why that is?

Check the box on the lower left corner on this site: http://lightningsoul.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem had nothing to do with FF29 but with the implementation of the JavaScript.
I had to add a leading / in order to implement it for pages like http://lightningsoul.com/media/vid/1934 etc.